# How to assign SELECT statement to variable and execute that variable using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to assign the "SELECT" query to variable and then want to execute that variable and display result but got stuck while quoting single quotes.

**Example**:

```
 create or replace function test() returns setof record as
 $BODY$
 Declare
      query1 varchar;
 Begin

      query1 := SELECT DISTINCT c."Name", c."Address"
            INTO  temptable
        FROM table1 l
        INNER JOIN tablename c on l."Name" = c."Name"
        ORDER BY "Name";

  /* Here need to execute query1 and get result of it */
 end;
 $BODY$
 language plpgsql;
```

**Question**: How to give proper single quote for select statement and execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't really want a `select .. into ... ...` as that is the non-standard (obsolete, historic) syntax for `create table as select`.

As you declared your function as `returns setof record` I assume you actually want to return a result set. It would be better to use `returns table (...)` instead because then the usage of the function is easier.

Finally I don't see the reason for dynamic SQL here, but I assume you simply didn't tell us the whole story.

The following should work (untested):

```
create or replace function test() 
   returns table (name text, address text)
as
 $BODY$
 Declare
      query1 varchar;
 Begin
    query1 := 'SELECT DISTINCT c."Name", c."Address"
        FROM table1 l
        INNER JOIN tablename c on l."Name" = c."Name"
        ORDER BY "Name"';

    return query execute query1;
 end;
 $BODY$
 language plpgsql;
```

This assumes that `Name` and `Address` are both `varchar` or `text` columns. If they are not you need to adjust the `returns table (text, text)` part.

But given your example there is no need for dynamic SQL or even PL/pgSQL, a simple SQL function will do (and will usually be much faster):

```
create or replace function test() 
   returns table (name text, address text)
as
$body$
 SELECT DISTINCT c."Name", c."Address"
 FROM table1 l
   INNER JOIN tablename c on l."Name" = c."Name"
 ORDER BY "Name"';
$body$
language sql;
```

<sup>You should also avoid quoted identifiers. They are more trouble than they are worth in the long run. Just create your tables without quoting the column names.</sup>